# Not smooth translation

Tags: javafx, timeline, smoothing

I'm using the `TranslateTransition` to move an `ImageView` from out to the center of the stage window. This is the issue: the animation jumps. The motion of the `ImageView` is not smooth and linear. I tried enabling the `-Dcom.sun.scenario.animation.vsync=true, -Dcom.sun.scenario.animation.adaptivepulse=true` properties but without success. Thinking that the issues may be due to the pc power I run the application more powerfull and  different pc (I7 with 16gb of ram) but again without success, the animation is not smooth.
I read that the JavaFX timer auto compute the pulse according with the screen hz.
So can you help me to undestand why the animation is not smooth?

MVCE:

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MCVE extends Application
{
    private Stage   stage;
    private String  title   = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(MCVE.class, new java.lang.String[] { "--filename=./template.fxml" });
    }

    public MCVE()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        stage = primaryStage;

        final Parameters params = getParameters();

        // load fxml
        final AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(new File(params.getNamed().get("filename")).toURI().toURL());
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);

        // setup stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinWidth(page.getPrefWidth());
        stage.setMinHeight(page.getPrefHeight());
        stage.setWidth(page.getPrefWidth());
        stage.setHeight(page.getPrefHeight());

        stage.setTitle(title);

        // setup full screen mode
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() >= 2)
                {
                    stage.setFullScreen(!stage.isFullScreen());
                }
            }
        };
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);

        // setup scene
        setupScene();

        // open the stage
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param nodeName
     * @return
     */
    private Node getNode(String nodeName)
    {
        return stage.getScene().lookup("#" + nodeName.toLowerCase());
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void setupScene()
    {
        String userdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        // slide node
        final Node node = getNode("image");

        long inTime = 5000;
        long pauseTime = 3000;
        long outTime = 5000;

        TranslateTransition in = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(inTime));
        in.setFromX(-1280);
        in.setToX(node.translateXProperty().getValue());
        in.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_IN);

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(pauseTime));

        TranslateTransition out = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(outTime));
        out.setFromX(node.translateXProperty().getValue());
        out.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
        out.setToX(1280 + node.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());

        final SequentialTransition  timeline = new SequentialTransition(node, in, pause, out);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

    }

}
```

[Here](http://www.fantalegaivillaggi.it/public/MVCE_Resources.zip) download the required resources.
Save them into the working folder.

This is the dump with  -Dprism.verbose=true

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using platform text rasterizer
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
OS Information:
Windows 7 build 7601
D3D Driver Information:
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650
\\.\DISPLAY1
Maximum supported texture size: 8192
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Driver atiumd64.dll, version 8.14.10.678
Pixel Shader version 3.0
Device : ven_1002, dev_9480, subsys_02051025
Max Multisamples supported: 4
```

Cheers,
Fabio

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @James_D above the code that I'm using to create the timeline node.

Comment: Please create an MCVE

Comment: I can't download the required resources. But since these are not really the issue, you should create an example that doesn't rely on them. (The "minimal" part of MCVE.)

Comment: @James_D resources download fixed. Please can you check it again? Many thanks

Comment: That's still not really an MCVE... however, it runs perfectly smoothly for me. What platform (JDK version, OS) are you using?

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_25 x64 version. [link] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77925083/javafx_video.mov) Here a video of what I see. Thank you again

Comment: QuickTime won't open that for some reason... :/

Comment: @James_D Video file converted using H.264 codec. You should see it. [link] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77925083/javafx_video.mov).

Comment: @James_D Did u see new video? Can  you help me to understand why the animation is not smooth? I tryed this code in a powerfull machine but without success. Cheers, Fabio

Comment: @Fabio Latini: I have that too on my system. I noticed that it occurs more often when I have multiple JavaFX programs run simultaneously. But that may be also a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set **cache** and **cacheHint** on the node(image) for smooth animation, i.e.

```
 node.setCache(true);
 node.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
```

Check [JavaFX 8 Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) for more information